# How to Download 4 files at a time

Tags: php, ajax

How to Download 4 files at a time which are stored in database? It is combination of pdf,png,jpg,jpeg files. I want to download all the four files on a click on download button.

Comment: may i suggest something like, making a zip file on the fly before sending it to download

Comment: agreed with zipping it. As a user, I would be annoyed if I had to accept four separate file download dialogs.

Comment: Use this solution, but multiple times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095246/using-javascript-to-send-an-http-attachment-to-the-user-open-browsers-save-as

Comment: @pranali You will find a lot of info to [ZIP multiple files and download here](http://www.webinfopedia.com/multiple-file-download-by-creating-zip-file-in-PHP.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Create a .zip file using php](http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php), then once you have the 1 file, link to it so that the user can right click-download as or something similar.

This way, it be faster than downloading 4 separate files.

(link found on Google, i'm sure there are better tutorials out there, but google really is your friend).